# How to configure Macports installed application for first time?

Tags: macports

I'm new to macports, and I'm really lost.  I am trying to download PSPP (statistical software) via the GNU open software project using MacPorts, and installation completed without hiccups but I do not know how to proceed.  How do I configure the application I just installed?  Also, how do I get it to start up at automatically at boot?

I know this is a basic question, but I'd really appreciate the help!  The MacPort QuickStart help questions are very confusing to me.  Thanks!

Comment: 1) Macports has very little to do with this question; it did its job and installed the software. From this point on your question is really about how to configure a specific piece of software. 2) Macports is pretty old, the modern package manager for OS X is http://brew.sh.

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is how to start the application. This largely depends on the application you installed, so PSPP in your case. Consult the documentation of PSPP (e.g. on their Website) to learn more.

In most cases, software installs a number of executables that you should run to start it. You can get a list of all files installed by PSPP using MacPorts by running

```
$> port contents pspp
```

Since this list will likely be huge, you can limit it to the locations where executables are usually installed:

```
$> port contents pspp | grep -E '/s?bin/'
```

For the PSPP port, it seems MacPorts also creates an .app wrapper. Check for `/Applications/MacPorts/` – there should be a `PSPP.app` there.